# send X11 window from local PC, with VNC over SSH to remote PC, without touching remote PC

Tags: ssh, vnc, vnc-server, vnc-viewer

Let's say I have two Linux PCs: LOCAL, where I sit physically, and REMOTE, that is connected to projector. So,
while sitting at my LOCAL computer, I want launch a graphical application, let's say google-chrome, and I want that to show up on the remote computer - but I don't want to physically go to remote computer and start 'vncviewer' every time I want to do this. I don't even want to go there to log in. How can I solve this problem?

In other words, I DO NOT want to do this every time:

1. Start x11vnc server on local pc:

   ```
   LOCAL_PC ~$ x11vnc
   # and do some graphical stuff, like: 
   LOCAL_PC ~$ firefox &
   ```
2. and then, physically go to the remote computer and start the vnc client:

   ```
   REMOTE_PC ~$ vncviewer LOCAL_PC_IP
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the solution. 
(to make sure this is the thing you are looking for: **this solution will help you to open graphical applications on your computer and display it on remote computers monitor**)

## Short version

```
    REMOTE_PC ~$ xhost +localhost
    LOCAL_PC ~$ x11vnc -geometry 2560x1440 &
    LOCAL_PC ~$ ssh UserName@REMOTE_PC_IP "export DISPLAY=:0.0 xeyes && cinnamon-screensaver-command -d && vncviewer LOCAL_PC_IP"
```

p.s. I don't know if the first line is even necessary

## Long version :

REMOTE_PC -is the pc that is connected to projector

LOCAL_PC -is the pc that you sit on.

#### things to do on REMOTE_PC with IP - REMOTE_PC_IP

to enable localhost x controlling. PHYSICALLY go and type that, u need to do it once.

```
    xhost +localhost
```

#### things to do on LOCAL_PC with IP - LOCAL_PC_IP

start vnc server

```
    x11vnc -geometry 2560x1440
```

ssh to remote pc

```
    ssh username@REMOTE_PC_IP
```

export display, unlock screen on that remote pc (like you entered password and logged in), start client and connect to server that was started on local PC.

```
    export DISPLAY=:0.0 xeyes
    cinnamon-screensaver-command -d
    vncviewer LOCAL_PC_IP
```

p.s. instead of 
cinnamon-screensaver-command, you might need to use gnome-screensaver-command